# sinh/cosh of complex number on TI-89

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

Is there another way of calculating sinh(1+j) for example instead of decomposing in sin and cos?

Comment: Do all the trig. & hyperbolic functions take purely real arguments?

Comment: The Ti-89 can compute with complex numbers, but unless you require a numerical result, it will develop this expression into $\sinh 1\cos 1+i \cosh 1\sin 1$. What would you expect?

Comment: Just in case: the imaginary $i$ is found with "2nd-catalog" (that is the blue i above the "catalog" touch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am curious what will show up here.

My view is that the direct definition is in terms of the exponential function:
$$
\sinh(x+iy) = \frac{e^{x+iy} - e^{-(x+iy)}}{2}
$$
so unless your exponential function is ready for complex arguments, you will at some point have to evaluate $e^{ix}$ and there use cosine and sine.